# What countries currently adopt anti-natalist policies?

Tags: policy, population

What countries currently adopt [anti-natalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antinatalism) policies?

As defined in the political issues section of Birth Control wiki:

> Conversely, other countries have policies to reduce the birth rate
>   (for example, China's one-child policy which was in effect from 1978
>   to 2015). Policies to increase the crude birth rate are known as
>   pro-natalist policies, and policies to reduce the crude birth rate are
>   known as anti-natalist policies.

**Note**:

- I'm looking for policies that are currently in place or have been disbanded in the last decade.
- I would like to exclude China's [one child policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-child_policy) as to me that's
  a widely known policy already.
- I'm not talking about legalising abortion because that stems from several issues, not just population growth control. I'm talking about ways to control the crude birth rate of citizens of such countries.

Comment: A list-based questions are not good fit for SE. You should be more specific to prevent speculations what is anti-natalist and what is not. For many people, legalizing abortion is very strong anti-natalist. So almost all European countries would be anti-natalist from that perspective.

Comment: List based questions on Politics.SE are perfectly fine (in most cases depending on how broad it is) but that's subjective and out of the scope of the question. However, I've edited it to align with your comment.

Comment: Are you looking for examples were the policies affect all parts of the population alike, or do you want to include eugenic policies that only affect certain groups (e.g. Sweden used to have a policy of forced sterilisations for people with "undesirable" traits, which allegedly still persists for transgender persons) ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff I'm looking for policies that influence the whole country yes, but that's an interesting topic regardless and I'll look into it,  I didn't know that existed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Uzbekistan [they used to](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-17612550)/still sterilize women after they had their second child to prevent population increase. I can try to find other examples but there isn't many.